# Is there any statistical test to confirm if a dependent variable converges to a value as the independent variable approaches infinity?

Tags: statistical-significance, nonlinear-regression, convergence

I have a very large table with 40,000 elements, and the dependent variable appears to approach a value as the independent variable gets larger. Is there any test I can perform to confirm if the dependent variable approaches a value as the independent variable goes to infinity?

I have considered using a chi square independence test and a linear regression slope test, but I do not know if these are the best tests for this case. Can someone please help?

Comment: No. There is no such test.

Comment: 40000 is awfully far from infinity :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't any model with logit-link doing exactly this? $y$ approaches $1$ if $x$ goes to $\infty$? Since classical logistic regression requires your $y$ to be binary, you could use a beta regression and standardize your independent variable to take on only values between 0 and 1.

This would not exactly be a *confirmation* of the convergence to a certain value, but investigating model fit and comparing with other models, e.g. a linear model, could provide insights regarding the appropriateness of this model.